# No coverage files located, please try use `-f`, or change the project root with `-R`

Tags: flutter, gitlab, gitlab-ci, code-coverage, codecov

I have files in the folder:
coverage/lcov.info

and I will upload the file using codecov uploader version 0.2.4 in CI Gitlab (using flutter)
but got error

```
There was an error running the uploader: No coverage files located, please try use `-f`, or change the project root with `-R`
```

how can i fix this? please help

[image]

Comment: you can use option -f along with that

Answer (score 3):

Probably you didn't create any coverage report before. Try:

```
pip install codecov
pip install pytest-cov
pytest --cov=./ --cov-report=xml
codecov
```